# Regex to match a series of URLs

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex to match a bunch of URL with the structure like:

```
env1-www-uk.my.domain.com
env2-www-uk.my.domain.com
http://env1-www-uk.my.domain.com
https://env1-www-uk.my.domain.com
```

There can be different numbers for each environment (env1, env2, env3 etc.) and I would like to match all of them at once. I also need to match everything in the URL which comes afterwards so things like:

```
env1-www-uk.my.domain.com/something123
env2-www-uk.my.domain.com/some%20more/stuff-too/
```

I wrote a regex but it does not work as I expected, could you please point me to the right direction?

```
^(https:\/\/|http:\/\/)env[0-9]{1}\-www\-uk\.my\.domain\.com.+
```

Comment: Do all your URLs start with `env` and end with `.com` does it has any other end? like `.co` or `.net`?

Comment: Yes, all of them.

Comment: what programming language are you using?

Comment: I am using C# but I need this for IIS URL Rewrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
/^(?:htt(?:ps|p):\/\/)?(.*com)(\/?.*)$/gm
```

check its working here: https://regex101.com/r/WZkFWz/1

Explanation:

```
^                        start of the line
(?:htt(?:ps|p):\/\/)?    non capture group, which matches either http or https, ? at the end indicates this can be optional
(.*com)                  capturing group, matches everything including after http or from the start of the string till .com 
(\/?.*)                  captures everything after .com till the end of the line
$                        end of the line
```